# From MySQL to Objective-C

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode

I have a mysql database with informations about users. Now I want to work with them in my iPhone app. Is there a way to bring the stuff from mysql to objective-c? 
It's not an option to use the mysql c api because my web server just allows php.

Greekings, Valle.

Comment: "The fruit-bowl at lunch doesn't have any Ham in it!" -> PHP is a programming language, MySQL is a Database. Not the same thing. Your web host definitely supports it...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think you explained your problem very well. Shared web hosting solutions usually don't offer access to MySQL servers from outside, it means you can access only from their servers (like PHP scripts on your hosting).

Solution to this is usually simple web service - REST, XML-RPC, SOAP.

Web service is some application that can be written in PHP and is running on your web hosting. This application returns data (usually in XML or JSON) via specific URL.

Example:
From your native iPhone you call

> http://yourserver.com/webservice/?what=episode-list&tvshow=battlestar-galactica

and output will be XML with list of episodes.

Comment: Its best not to regurgitate the phrase *google this*, this is what StackOverflow is trying to be - the alternative to google for programming answers/solutions. Look at the right hand-side of this page, there's *Related* heading with possible answers... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but maybe this can help:

1. You can **serve the information from your database with PHP** (some **XML** or **JSON** can be useful) and then **parse it on your iPhone App**.
2. Or you can **export your database and convert it to SQLite** and use it directly on your iPhone.

With a bit more information maybe we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create an Application Programming Interface (API), in PHP on the web server that your Objective-C program will talk to using the devices internet connection.

Effectively you want to create special url's and request parameters your web server will use to pull database information, parse them into JSON or XML, and return them as plain text.

Inside your Objective-C application you will craft these URL's and parse the incoming JSON or XML into actionable data for your app.